# How to transform a 3 dimensional dataset into an array in python

Tags: python, dataset, netcdf4

I have a big .nc (netCDF) file, with dimensions of (744, 301, 301), which correspond to (time, lat, long) for temperature. Basically this means for a specific time, lat and long it will tell you the temperature. I want to make the data look like this:

```
id  temp time lat long
1
2
3
```

Unfortunately I'm not so familiar with Python, my idea so far is to use a huge for loop, but surely there's an easy way to do what I want to do! Thanks in advance.

Comment: make a data frame using python package pandas and provide indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read a netcdf with [`xarray`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/) and then send the result to pandas with the [`xr.Dataset.to_dataframe`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.to_dataframe.html) method:

```py
df = xr.open_dataset("myfile.nc").to_dataframe()
```

See the user guide section on [Working with Pandas](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/pandas.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you! I have to fiddle a bit with the resulting dataframe but it was definitely a step in the right direction!